# Swift and watchkit: pushControllerWithName not being called at all

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have always used the pushControlledWithName method in swift/watchkit to move to another interface controller, basically like this:

```
self.pushControllerWithName("newinterfacecontroller", context: nil)
```

In some of my projects, when I put this in a function (like where the user presses a button) it simply doesn't get called at all. No errors, just as if the code isn't there at all. If I create a new test project and try it it works. I am baffled as to what's going on here.

Example of what happens:

```
    @IBAction func button1Action() {

    println("test")

    self.pushControllerWithName("newinterfacecontroller", context: nil)

}
```

Pressing the button will print "test" in the console, but it doesn't try to move to the new interface controller (with identifier "newinterfacecontroller") at all.

Comment: Is self is in a page-based navigation?

Comment: you mean where I have control dragged  it to another interface controller, so that the user can swipe to switch interface controllers? Yes. Unfortunately the watchkit simulator never works for me unless I swipe to another blank interface controller and then back to the main one (only then will it load) as otherwise I get the spinning ball of death and nothing loads.

Comment: I found that that's the problem - if there is paged based navigation, the self.pushControllerWithName isn't called. Hopefully I can get the simulator actually working properly so it loads without having to switch interface controllers.

Comment: Great then. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've figured this out from the comments, but page-based interfaces are technically modals and not navigation-stack interfaces.

You can present modals from anywhere, but you can only push onto a navigation stack from a non-modal.